# Update css file and minify it

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I made a website for a customer with php, html, javascript and css. I used sass in the first place to get my styles done, but now the customer wants to be able to change typo and main colors. I can add in the admin the functionality but instead of sass I would use php (header) to overwrite the css styles needed. I would prefer to use my sass file but the host doesn't support ruby.
Is there any better solution to get the same result? Can I compile .scss files in the host?

Comment: You want the customer to change the whole CSS files or does the customer just wants to alter font-family and primary color?

Comment: have you looked at [`php-sass`](https://github.com/panique/php-sass) project? I am removing the ruby tag since this question does not actually require ruby in any fashion.

Comment: maybe you can use an outside webservice to talk to a ruby server at the time of the css changing, then save the compiled css to the php server. this is how i run the closure compiler on JS from php...

Comment: The customer can only change typo and primary color with a select list and color picker, not directly in the css file.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 solutions:

1) A solution could be to replace all occurrences of typo and primary colors with Sass variables and add them in a new file fx: _custom_customer_updates.scss. By doing so, you have 1 custom Sass file that only holds the variables that can be changed. When the variables are updated, you update the Sass file via PHP and then use the suggestion from @engineersmnky and get the CSS updated based on all your Sass files.

Or...

2) you could inline the CSS changes right after you include your .css file in the HTML header. Then the latest changes will always overwrite the defaults and your Sass files are not changed by any other than you.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="all" />
<style>
body {
  color: green;
  font-familiy: Arial;
}
</style>
```